# Vector equation of line of intersection of two planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, plane-geometry

I am interested in finding a vector equation of intersection of the two planes $4x + y - 7z = 0$ and $2x - 3y + 4z = -8$. (This is from a past A-level Further Maths paper).

The mark scheme substitutes in $x=0$, $y = 0$ and $z = 0$ respectively to get the points $(0,56/17,8/17)$, $(-28/15,0,-16/15)$, $(-4/7,16/7,0)$ and then deduces that the direction vector of the line of intersection is $17{\bf i}+30{\bf j} + 14{\bf k}$. Then, the equation of the line is expressed in the form ${\bf r} = 56/17{\bf j} + 8/17{\bf k} + \lambda (17{\bf i}+30{\bf j} + 14{\bf k}).$

*How is this direction vector deduced?*

Comment: I haven't checked the math, but the three points given will be on the line of intersection as they satisfy the equations of both planes. To obtain a direction vector choose any two of the points and subtract the coordinates of one from the other. You can multiply the vector by a suitable constant to obtain integral components.

Comment: They clearly got it as the cross-product of the two plane normals:$$(2,-3,4)\times(4,1,-7) = (17, 30, 14)$$The line of intersection lies in each plane, so its direction vector must point along both planes, and therefore must be perpendicular to both plane normals. In 3D this uniquely defines the direction, up to sign. But the cross-product of two vectors is also perpendicular to both, so it must also point in that direction. (Note though that while this trick only works in 3D, Michael Cohen's method works in any number of dimensions.)

Comment: I'd like to add to the above comment that, having taught A-Level Further Maths (a UK-based qualification) , I would expect the  mark scheme used by the OP to contain both methods. The cross-product method is probably less work.

Comment: Thanks both :) It was very simple but the logic in the mark scheme was very unclear. It simply gave all the points with $x$, $y$ and $z$ equalling zero respectively and then wrote "$\implies \text{direction} = 17{\bf i} + 30{\bf j} + 14{\bf k}$"...